# Oracle Database Client Installation 12c minimal install - Centos / Red Hat 7

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, installation, centos-7

I'm looking at reducing the Linux package prerequisites when installing the Oracle Database Client 12c on the below headless application server / stack:

- Install file: V839967-01.zip
- Application server Linux OS: CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
- Application server platform: x86_64
- Database Server hosting DB: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
- Database Server Linux OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
- Database Server platform: x86_64

The below Oracle guide, on page 3-9 includes a number of packages that seem unnecessary for example smartmontools.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lacli/database-client-installation-guide-linux.pdf

The installer is being run silently using a response file:

```
./runInstaller -silent -force -debug waitForCompletion=true -responseFile /u01/app/12c_installer/client/client.rsp
```

There is also no need for the 32bit client on the application server.

Would trimming the package selection down to the following packages introduce any problems? :

```
bc.x86_64
binutils.x86_64
compat-libcap1.x86_64
compat-libstdc++-33.x86_64
glibc.x86_64
glibc-devel.x86_64
ksh.x86_64
libaio.x86_64
libaio-devel.x86_64
libgcc.x86_64
libstdc++.x86_64
libstdc++-devel.x86_64
make.x86_64
net-tools.x86_64
sysstat.x86_64
```

Comment: Please share the link to download these files. (V839967-01.zip)

Answer (score 2):

So you want to perform a minimal install and instead of using the [Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) which is below 100MB with minimal requirements, you chose the full client that may occupy over 1 GB space and requires additional packages to be installed, but you want to go against the documentation and have an irregular configuration, that is still way more than what you would have to do by using the Instant Client.

Just use the Instant Client and follow the [installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html#ic_x64_inst) of that.

Comment: @John McLean  I agree with Balazs Papp.  You need a supported installation.  By removing packages it might work until an update or rarely used feature is required and then you will be spending hours trying to find the root cause.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. I'll have a look at the Oracle Instant Client.